# Why I always get same content from MediaWiki API call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, mediawiki

I am using the MediaWiki API to get images through AJAX call.
I used the MediaWiki Sandbox to create an api call to query these images from Wikimedia-Commons. I used the title 'California'.

This is the url:

```
var url_wiki = "https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=California&list=allimages&ailimit=10&format=json&callback=?";
```

And this is the AJAX call I am using:

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: url_wiki,
 data: {
   action:'query',
   format:'json'
 },
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(result){
   console.log(result);
 }
```

Now, it seems to work fine, since I get 10 images related to 'California' (even though they are quite weird):
[Console Result for 'California'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGs8r.png)

BUT, now my question is: **If I change my url attribute 'title' and I type 'Europe', for example, instead of California, I am still getting the same images from 'California'...**

New url:

```
var url_wiki = "https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Europe&list=allimages&ailimit=10&format=json&callback=?";
```

[Console Result for 'Europe' -> Same images!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acKNP.png)

I can't understand this... something is wrong in my API call?

Comment: These images don’t seem to relate to either topic. They just seem to be the top 10 alphanumerically sorted images.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed they were tagged to 'California' for some reason...

Comment: I think that `list=allimages` just return first 10 images and ignore the title.

Comment: If I delete list=allimages I don't get any images, just the 'pages' result

Comment: @GeorgeMarti Nobody said anything about deleting `list=allimages`…

Answer (score 1):

The `titles` parameter is meant for `prop=` API modules (e.g. `prop=pageimages` or `prop=imageinfo`), it has no effect on list modules (`list=...` API calls). `allimages` returns all images, as the name suggests. Are you looking for the [search API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search)?